# How to expand parameter pack pattern in an "unzipping" manner?

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, parameter-pack

Say I have a variadic function, `foo`:

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args... args)
{
    // some work
}
```

I want to have a magic function, `bar`, that forwards its arguments to `foo` in the following manner:

Say if I call

```
bar(x, y, z);
```

It'll have the same effect as

```
foo(x.begin(), x.end(), y.begin(), y.end(), z.begin(), z.end());
```

How to implement such `bar()`?

```
template <typename... Args>
void bar(Args... args)
{
    // what should I put here?
    // foo( (args.begin(), args.end()) ... );  // doesn't work 
}
```

Comment: You're asking a lot of C++ here and are expecting it to be a dynamic programming language, which it isn't. Why can't that other function work the same way? Why can't you pass this in as a `std::vector` of something?

Comment: @arnes It compiles, but it doesn't work.  You end up calling foo with only the `args.end` since the comma expression only returns the last expression.

Comment: I hate to say it but unless you use a macro I can't see a way to do this that doesn't wind up making a bunch of copies.

Comment: @NathanOliver i thought op meant doesn't compile, removing my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use C++17, apply `std::apply`:

```
template<class ...  Conts>
void bar(Conts&& ... c) {
    auto t = std::make_tuple( std::make_tuple(c.begin(),c.end())... );
    // tuple< tuple<C1.begin,C1.end>, tuple<C2.begin,C2.end>, ... >    [1]
    std::apply( [](auto&&... tuples){
            auto oneTuple = std::tuple_cat(std::forward<decltype(tuples)>(tuples)...);
            // tuple< C1.begin(), C1.end(), C2.begin(), C2.end(), ...>   [2]
            std::apply([](auto&&... its){
                foo(std::forward<decltype(its)>(its)...); /// all iterators begin/end    [3]
            }, oneTuple);
        }, t);
}
```

1. Create tuple of `tuple<begin,end>` for all entries
2. Use `apply` to get all tuples created in first step and make one out of them by concatenating - use `tuple_cat`
3. Use again `apply` to extract all iterators from tuple created in second step, pass them all into `foo`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9yR4Xw)

Comment: Sorry, but... why `std::tuple_cat()` inside `std::apply()` and not immediately creating `t`? I mean: why non simply `template <typename ...  Conts>
void bar (Conts && ... c) {
    auto t = std::tuple_cat ( std::make_tuple(c.begin(),c.end())... );
    std::apply([](auto && ... vals)
               {foo(std::forward<decltype(vals)>(vals)...);},
               t);
}` ?

Comment: @max66 Yep, now I see it, you are completely right, one `apply` too much. Nice short version :)